# jQuery Hover Random Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set up a function that hovers and "de-hovers" on a random element in a class every 5 seconds. Thus far I have the `onhover` working with the following:

```
jQuery.fn.random = function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 56);  
    return jQuery(this[randomIndex]);
};
var timer = window.setInterval(function () {$('.graphic-container img').random().mouseover();}, 5000);
```

There are 56 fixed elements in the class, thus the " * 56"

For the life of me I can't figure out how to get the `mouseout` event working on that random element? This must happen before the next random element is hovered on.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery.fn.random = function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 56);  
    return jQuery(this[randomIndex]);
};
var prev;
var timer = window.setInterval(function () {
    if(prev){
        prev.mouseleave();
    }
    prev = $('.graphic-container img').random().mouseenter();
}, 5000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DjyWA/)

Comment: Would you maybe know how to call the mouseleave function on all the elements in a class - in this case in `.graphic-container`? Because when I hover over the containing element for these elements, I don't want two things in the hover state.

Comment: @user1795229 you might have to handle this in the hover function like in my example remove the `test` class from all other elements.

Comment: @user1795229 to call `mouserleave` you can use `$('.graphic-container img').mouseleave()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var timer = window.setInterval(function () {
   $('.graphic-container img').random().mouseover().delay(800).mouseout();
}, 5000);
```